# closing connection in mongoos.js after test finishes with mocha.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

```
before(function (done) {
  mongoose.connection.close();
  done();
});
```

I'm doing tests using mocha testing framework after the test finishes my terminal is still running,
and I found that method in the documentation but I'm getting an error says

```
     Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called;
     if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\test\demo_test.js)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the promises so you need to listen to it. You can use async/await or then/catch:

```
before(async function (done) {
  await mongoose.connection.close();
  done();
});
```

Also, you should close the connection in after instead of before. Check [this](https://davidecaruso.github.io/2020/03/26/mongodb-integration-tests-mocha/) for refactoring your test code.

Comment: oh i was searching for that thanks it worked!